# How to groupby and assign an array to a column in python-pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Given a data frame `df` like that:

```
a     b    
2     nan
3     nan
3     nan
4     nan
4     nan
4     nan 
5     nan
5     nan 
5     nan
5     nan
...
```

A critical rule is that each number `n` in `a` repeat `n-1` rows. And my expected output is:

```
a     b    
2     1
3     1
3     2
4     1
4     2
4     3
5     1
5     2
5     3
5     4
...
```

Thus the number `m` in `b` is a list from `1` to `n-1`. I tried it in this way:

```
df.groupby('a').apply(lambda x: np.asarray(range(x['a'].unique()[0])))
```

But the result is a list in one row, which is not what I want.

Could you please tell me how to implement it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
df['b'] = df.groupby('a').cumcount() + 1
print (df)
   a  b
0  2  1
1  3  1
2  3  2
3  4  1
4  4  2
5  4  3
6  5  1
7  5  2
8  5  3
9  5  4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# make a column that is 0 on the first occurrence of a number in a and 1 after
df['is_duplicated'] = df.duplicated(['a']).astype(int)

# group by values of a and get the cumulative sum of duplicates
# add one since the first duplicate has a value of 0
df['b'] = df[['a', 'is_duplicated']].groupby(['a']).cumsum() + 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your great answer! Wonderful!